# Why am I getting Segmentation fault. Raspberry pi 4 C Programming

Tags: c, raspberry-pi4

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
//#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
//#include <linux/input-polldev.h>
//#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*
    MAHIR SHAHRIAR 
    30027575 
    CPSC 359 
    ASSIGNMENT 2
*/

#define GPIO_CLOCKPIN 23   // pin used for clock output GPIO 11 (SPI_SCLK)
#define GPIO_LATCHPIN 21   // pin used for latch output GPIO 9 (SPI_MISO)
#define GPIO_DATAPIN 19    // pin used for data input from controller GPIO 10 (SPI_MOSI)
#define GPIO_POWERPIN 1    // 3.3 VOLT POWER SOURCE Programmble input to set high/low
#define GPIO_GROUNDPIN 9   // Pin used for grounding
#define GPIO_BASEADDRESS 0xfe200000 // Base address used to offset to other registers




//volatile unsigned *gpio = (unsigned*)0xfe200000; // gpio pointer to base address
volatile uint32_t *gpio = (unsigned*)0xfe200000;
volatile uint32_t *GPFSEL1 = (unsigned*)0xfe200000 + 0x04/4; //pointer to register GPFSEL1 for pins 10-19
volatile unsigned *GPFSEL2 = (unsigned*)0xfe200000 + 0x08/4; //pointer to register GPFSEL2 for pins 20-29
volatile unsigned *GPSET0 = (unsigned*)0xfe200000 + 0x1c/4; //pointer to register GPSET0 for setting high
volatile unsigned *GPCLR0 = (unsigned*)0xfe200000 + 0x28/4; //pointer to register GPCLR0 for setting low
volatile unsigned *GPLEV0 = (unsigned*)0xfe200000 + 0x34/4; //pointer to register GPLEV0 for reading data from pin
volatile unsigned *GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REG1 = (unsigned*)0xfe200000 + 0xe8/4; //pointer to register for controlling pull up pull down



// INIT GPIO Function takes user inputs for Initializing a particular GPIO Pin number.
// It takes data such as the PIN NUMBBER , string "input" or "output" ,
// string "high" or "low "  and  string "pullup" or "pulldown"
// Depending on the arguments passed into the Init_GPIO function or subroutine
static void Init_GPIO(int pin_number, char type, char high_low, char pullup_pulldown) {

  // setting valueinput valueoutput and mask to set the input output of the pin type
  int valueinput = 0b000 << ( (pin_number-10)*3 );   // bits to be set for input
  int valueoutput = 0b001 << ( (pin_number-10)*3 );  // bits to be set for output
  int mask  = 0b111 << ( (pin_number-10)*3 );   //  for ensuring other bits dont change

// condition to check which register to access for the bits and setting to input or output based on
// function calls from main and arguments passed
  if(pin_number<=19){
    if(type == 'i'){
      printf("%x", GPFSEL1);
      //*GPFSEL1 = (*GPFSEL1 & ~mask) | (valueinput * mask);  //problem
    }
    else if(type == 'o'){
      //*GPFSEL1 = (*GPFSEL1 & ~mask) | (valueoutput * mask);
    }
    else{
      //no type specified
      printf("Input type not specified please use 'o' or 'i' ignore if not specifying output input type for pin\n");
    }
   if(pin_number > 19 && pin_number <=29 ){
     if(type == 'i'){
       //*GPFSEL2 = (*GPFSEL2 & ~mask) | (valueinput * mask);
     }
     else if(type == 'o'){
       //*GPFSEL2 = (*GPFSEL2 & ~mask) | (valueoutput * mask);
     }
     else{
       //no type specified
       printf("Input type not specified please use 'o' or 'i' ignore if not specifying output input type for pin\n");
     }
   }
// Setting the pin to either high or low
  if(high_low == 'h'){
    //*GPSET0 = 1 << pin_number;
  }
  else if(high_low == 'l'){
    //*GPCLR0 = 1 << pin_number;
  }
  else{
    // high low not specified
    printf("high low not specified please use 'h' or 'l' ignore if not specifying highlow for pin\n");
  }
}
// Setting if the pin uses pull up or pull down register
int value_pullup = 0b01 << ( (pin_number -16)*2 );
int value_pulldown = 0b10 << ( (pin_number -16)*2 );
mask = 0b11 << ( (pin_number -16)*2 );

if(pullup_pulldown == 'p'){
  //*GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REG1 = ( *GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REG1 & ~mask ) | (value_pullup) & mask;
}
else if(pullup_pulldown == 'n'){
  //*GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REG1 = ( *GPIO_PUP_PDN_CNTRL_REG1 & ~mask ) | (value_pulldown) & mask;
}
else {
  // user does not set any pull up or pull down value for the assigned pin
  printf("pull up pull down not specified please use 'p' or 'n' ignore if not specifying pullup pulldown for pin\n");
}
}

void main() {

     printf("pointer address %p " , gpio);
     Init_GPIO(18, 'i', 'l', 'p');
     volatile uint32_t valueinput = 0b000 << ( (18-10)*3 );   // bits to be set for input
  volatile uint32_t valueoutput = 0b001 << ( (18-10)*3 );  // bits to be set for output
  volatile uint32_t mask  = 0b111 << ( (18-10)*3 );
     *GPFSEL1 = (*GPFSEL1 & ~mask) | (valueinput * mask);
    


    
    
    
}
```

I am getting segmentation error for the last line in main. I dont know why this is doing that. How do I fix the issue I am trying to change the bits in the register GPFSEL1 for the raspberry pi 4 GPIO  for changing the input mode by changing bits to 000 for my pin 18 for putting in into input mode. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unlikely the problem, but why are you creating a pointer to an `unsigned` and assign it to an `uint32_t*`? Wouldn't it make sense to create the pointer to an `uint32_t*` instead?

Comment: Another thing: You have defined the base address pointer `gpio` so use it in all the following calculations. `olatile uint32_t *GPFSEL1 = gpio + 1;` etc.

Comment: Userspace processes have no direct access to physical addresses, they are running in virtual address space. You should either use userspace API to GPIO, e.g. libgpiod, or write your own device driver.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Since they defined these as variables at file scope, they can't write what might look like more sensible code, such as `volatile uint32_t *GPFSEL1 = base + 0x04;` Because this isn't a constant expression and can't be used to initialize a static storage variable. I'd probably implement all of these as macros instead: `#define GPFSEL1 (*(base + 0x04))`.

Comment: @Lundin Ah, yes!

Comment: Figured out the problem I could not access the physical address. Therefore I had to use mmap on the raspberry pi platform to access the registers.  I used int memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    uint32_t * map = (uint32_t *)mmap(
                        NULL,
                        4*1024,
                        (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE),
                        MAP_SHARED, 
                        memfd, 
                        GPIO_BASE);
                     
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
        printf("mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));    
    close(memfd);

Comment: and then map becomes my base address and i just do. *(map + 0x04/4) for example to access GPFSEL1 Registor  for GPIO

Comment: @GamblingMath Again you need to drop the "divide magic multiple of 4 with the magic number `4`", use pointer arithmetic instead. Do not write `*(map + 0x04/4)`, write `map[1]`.